# Validation Rule on case object

Tags: validation-rule

Could you please correct me this validation rule

```
AND(
    OR(
        RecordType.DeveloperName = 'RMA',
        RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Device_Swap'
    ),
    NOT(ISBLANK(Return_Label_Emailed_Sent__c)),
    ISBLANK(Date_Sent_Emailed__c),
    ISBLANK(Return_Label_ID__c),
    ISBLANK(Return_shipment_cost__c)
)
```

Case record types

- RMA
- Device_Swap

Fields

- Return_Label_Emailed_Sent__c   (Checkbox field)
- Date_Sent_Emailed__c   (Date/Time field)
- Return_Label_ID__c     (Text field)
- Return_shipment_cost__c (Number field)

These fields should be mandatory to update when case record type is RMA and Device_Swap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the right way to do this is:

```
AND(
    OR(
        RecordType.DeveloperName = 'RMA',
        RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Device_Swap'
    ),
    OR(
        NOT(Return_Label_Emailed_Sent__c),
        ISBLANK(Date_Sent_Emailed__c),
        ISBLANK(Return_Label_ID__c),
        ISBLANK(Return_shipment_cost__c)
    )
)
```

The only additional consideration is about "Return_Label_Emailed_Sent__c" field, to me, it doesn't make sense to turn a checkbox field required, I prefer user PickLists in these cases.

Comment: Thank you so much @Elvis Platini Giovanetti

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules trigger when the formula evaluates to *true*.

Right now, since you're `AND()`-ing all of the required fields together, your formula will only result in true when *all* of the required fields are blank.

To have the validation rule complain when *at least one* of the required fields are blank, you need to wrap your checks inside of an `OR()`.

You still want the top-level `AND()`, so your formula should end up looking like

```
AND(
    OR(
        /* record type checks */
    ),
    OR(
        /* blank field checks */
    )
)
```